# Convert string to normal text

Tags: c#, character-encoding

When I open one file it contains something like this:

```
&#73;&#116;&#39;&#115;&#32;&#116;&#104;&#97;&#116;
```

What is this and how do I convert it to ASCII ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is HTML encoding, use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` (in `System.Net` namespace):

```
string encoded = "&#73;&#116;&#39;&#115;&#32;&#116;&#104;&#97;&#116;";
string decoded = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
```

Comment: but html tag `<br>` not decoded or at least it not leaves new line

Comment: The original text had new lines but my text after decoding doesn't have new lines

Comment: Then encoding seems to be the problem, newlines (`\r\n` or `\n`) are different stuff than `<br />` tag.

Comment: You can convert linefeeds (newline to br) before you encode your string e.g. `myString = myString.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")` or something like that

Answer (score 2):

[`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Those are HTML entities. They represent ascii characters. You can decode them using [HttpUtility.HTMLDecode().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

If you're just trying to read this one line, you could also rename the file to a .html file and open it in your browser of choice. There are even [tools](http://centricle.com/tools/html-entities/) that do this online.

Answer (score 2):

The number between the &# ; is likely an ASCII code.
Convert the numbers manually or use the HTMLDecode to save yourself some time...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net Framework 4.0 or higher then the `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s)` will work.

I needed this solution for an SSRS report where only 3.5 was supported.  Since the namespace above wasn't available I went the alternate route of

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rawString)
```